# Where has en_SE gone in 21.10?

Tags: kubuntu, locale

I had a Kubuntu system (actually many) set up with en_SE.UTF-8 because it's the only locale that has: english, metric, YYYY/MM/DD and a few other non-stupid things. It was working great.

Then this morning I upgraded to 21.10 and this locale is gone. I used `locale-gen` and looked in some config files and there's no trace of it anywhere. So has it been renamed or do I need to generate it somehow ?

Comment: AFAIK that locale has never existed in glibc. You may want to try `en_DK.UTF-8`.

Comment: Yup, that seems almost perfect. I just wish there was clearer info/comparision about all those.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the locale `en_SE.UTF-8` doesn't actually exist.

But that hasn't stopped some enterprising individuals to actually make one:

https://gist.github.com/bmaupin/d64368e78cd359d309685fecbe2baf23

Go to the above Gist, scroll down to `installation.sh`, and just copy-paste the instructions.